Request: Require moderators to leave a message they themselves type, when closing a post
Some of my question posts have been closed with "off topic" or "lacking context" and nothing more than a generic link to the guidelines. After reading those I then still see no actionable change for me to make. As from my perspective, the guidelines are met.
When people considering answering the question have issue with it, they leave comments and those can then be addressed. Sometimes even after doing so, the topic then becomes mysteriously closed with "guidelines".
Why is the moderation happening with so little transparency?
Can we please get at least a note, comment, something to the original poster with ACTIONABLE things for them to address?
I have come to the conclusion that stackexchange sites are no longer worth my time to ask questions on, and especially not ones that need to be seen by more than ~10 people to find someone able to answer them, as they end up closed before then. I cannot imagine im alone in feeling like the question asker has an unreasonable burden to just ask a question, having to essentially read the minds of moderators.

4 views, me being one, and two down votes with no comments. What is the purpose of downvoting a feature request? If you don't feel its needed simply do not upvote it? By down voting you are saying this post itself is inappropriate on meta stack exchange. Yet surely it is the place to make such requests?

Downvotes on Meta are different. A downvote on a feature request captures an explicit disagreement with the feature request.

"What is the purpose of downvoting a feature request?" Well, for one thing, this isn't a feature request - you're asking users to do something, not for the site software to work differently.

Can you provide an example of a question that you believe was closed without sufficient feedback? I don't see any such questions in your recent network history, so I'm guessing they were deleted?

For the record: we generally call users with a diamond next to their name "moderators". Users that close vote on questions are regular users that earned the close vote privilege. Do you mean only "moderators" should leave a personal message for you or do you mean every single close voter? So on SO you would get 5 comments / messages from 5 users when a question gets closed? Maybe consider asking "leave open" voters to explain their rationale as well? Might turn in a big comment/message mess, like often happens on reddit. Which is a site we don't want to mimic, by intentional design.

You've been on Stack Overflow, for example, for almost 16 years, and you still don't know what a moderator is. That's ok, you're not obligated to know much about the site to use it, but if you're going to criticize and demand changes you'll stand a better chance of convincing people if you appear to know how and why the site works the way it does.


When people considering answering the question have issue with it, they leave comments and those can then be addressed.

They are not obliged to, by design.

Sometimes even after doing so, the topic then becomes mysteriously closed with "guidelines".

There's nothing mysterious about this. It is the system working exactly as designed and intended.
When someone leaves a comment indicating a problem with the question, that implies that said user has identified a reason the question should be closed. People who identify such reasons are responsible for helping close it. It is expected that people do not wait for even a moment before doing so.
Please make sure you understand that closing a question does not kill it. The point of closing a question is to prevent it from being answered until OP fixes it. Questions that can be fixed by others, just get fixed by others - that's why they are allowed to edit your post. Deletion is reserved for questions that are either fundamentally unfixable or which OP has abandoned after closure.
It is vital to the intended operation of the Stack Exchange network that questions are not answered as long as they don't meet the site's standards. That's because the purpose of Stack Exchange sites is not to operate a help desk or discussion forum. We don't wait for your question so that we can give an answer to you directly. Instead, we provide a means for you to contribute questions that you believe are missing from the site, which would help to build up a useful Q&A library. The idea is that by building up this library, everyone can benefit: others who have the same question can find it with a search engine, and then they don't have to ask.
For more details, please take the tour. Especially note the phrasing: "We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise."

Why is the moderation happening with so little [explanation]?

First, this isn't a matter of "transparency" - moderators aren't acting on private information, but on the content of your public posts.
Overwhelmingly, explanations simply aren't required: the generic close reasons explain the problem perfectly well. I've lost count of the times, for example, that someone has supposedly wondered why a question was closed as "primarily opinion-based" when it very clearly and explicitly solicited opinions, or as a duplicate when it's a cut-and-dried example of an extremely common problem that gets asked about all the time.
But also, moderation resources are incredibly strained as is. Stack Overflow, for example, has literally nearly a million to one ratio of user accounts to active moderators. Granted, a large fraction of accounts have never posted, or are throwaways that won't come back, but still.

Can we please get at least a note, comment, something to the original poster with ACTIONABLE things for them to address?

You do. The close reasons are clearly documented on each per-site meta. The message that appears automatically include links to the corresponding site documentation. The overwhelming majority of questions posted on Meta about these issues, however, demonstrate a complete failure to read those links.
If your question is off topic, then it isn't possible to give you actionable feedback on that question: anything you could do to fix it would make it a different question. If you mean "why doesn't it tell me where to post the question instead?" then there are two problems: 1) that sort of query belongs on a Meta site instead; 2) a large fraction of questions asked would not be suitable anywhere on the network.
If your question lacks context, the solution is to add appropriate context.

I cannot imagine im alone in feeling like

No, not even remotely. We get complaints like this all the time.
But every single one of them is underpinned by a fundamental misunderstanding of the Stack Exchange community and its purpose.

having to essentially read the minds of moderators.

First off: almost all question closure is done by community members with close-vote privileges, not "moderators". Complaints about how the site works are generally taken much more seriously when they are based in how the site actually works, and are made by people who have demonstrably researched these things.
No mind-reading is necessary. What's needed is to: a) read the publicly posted explanations of community standards; and b) on Stack Exchange sites, you post questions and get answers - you don't post questions to get answers. These sites are not about you - they aren't help desks, and the people who answer questions are not on call to help you.

I had a look at your network profile, and I don't see any closed, public questions anywhere. If you're in the habit of deleting your questions simply because they got closed, then that, too, is not interacting with the site as intended. When your question is closed, you are first expected to try to edit the question to fix problems and nominate it for reopening. If you need help figuring out specifically what information to add to a question (or what to remove, or where you should ask it instead...), again, that is a question for the site-specific Meta. (Use the specific-question tag for these.)
Asking questions on Stack Exchange is a privilege, not a right. Repeatedly asking poorly received questions, as well as serially deleting questions, can lead to varying kinds of rate limits (see also this Meta Stack Overflow FAQ and corresponding network-wide Help Center article).
I also noticed that your Stack Overflow user ID is lower than mine, and that in fact you've been around since 2008. That's impressive, but it certainly doesn't excuse ignorance.

Imagine how many fewer complaints you would receive if instead of a faceless close by vote and a generic link, it looks like three people with names who had typed "seems off topic because [..]". Its pretty basic right?

Please consider that what you are proposing has been proposed countless times already. You are not being misunderstood; you are being disagreed with.

If you want to understand the closure or get help, post on the relevant Meta site.
There are a few problems with requiring comments.
First, sometimes the post is obviously bad. I don't want to be forced to leave a comment when spending 5 minutes reading the Tour or Help Center pages would explain why the question is bad. Perhaps user onboarding (or "user activation", as it's called in the most recent post on upcoming initiatives) would be helpful, since my experience indicates that a lot of these obviously bad posts are from people new to a site or the network in general.
Then there's the problem of user engagement. Often, drive-by users don't engage with comments. Even if the Help Center doesn't explicitly address the problems with the post, users may not be around or willing to engage on improvement. Asking people to take the time to write personalized guidance when the person who needs that guidance isn't engaging with it is a waste of time.
Finally, comments have limited length. Often, getting into the details doesn't fit well. Even if they do fit, there are limited formatting options. When help is wanted, it's sometimes hard to do constructively.
I would strongly encourage anyone who actually wants to understand the rules and norms of the network or a particular site to engage on that site's Meta. Whenever there's a new Meta post, moderators see a notification. Often, power users often go there too, and they may see the Meta post when they didn't see the original. Not only can someone get guidance on writing a good question, but they may attract some attention when the good question is posted to get even better answers.

Moderators engaging individually within comments is not a good workflow for either them or the poster. What I would very much want though, is a single sentence that pertains directly to the reason for closure, visible to the poster only. I cannot imagine that is too much to ask for? It doesn't have to be any more detailed than appropriate to the situation. When the poster goes to repost a closed topic, they are asked to state a reason afterall. Where does that conversation thread go? Cannot it be visible?

Actually though, is this site im on right now, not the correct site for 'meta' topics not specific to a single community site? If its specifically a meta for just stackexchange.com then im in the wrong place.

You're in the right place, @James When you say "moderators" do you mean the same thing we mean? "Moderators" on Stack Exchange are elected volunteers who have special access and permissions - including the ability to instantly close or reopen any question rather than requiring consensus from others. Many people come to meta and refer to anyone with the ability to vote to close a question as a "moderator", which is not how the term is used here. While they have moderation privileges, these are available to anyone who earns the required reputation.

@James Yes, it is too much to ask for. Why should anyone voting to close be required or even asked to write a sentence that likely cannot convey how to fix the problems with the post and, even if it could, would likely go unread by the person who needs to see it? Anyone who actually wants to understand the rationale for closure and get more personalized help can go to the Meta site from wherever they asked their question.

"When the poster goes to repost a closed topic, they are asked to state a reason afterall." If you are reposting a closed question then you are fundamentally misusing the site. You are expected to edit the closed question so that it can be reopened, instead. And you are expected to know this, by reading the automatically provided information on the question - like the part where it suggests editing the question, and the word "edit" is even linked.

"What I would very much want though, is a single sentence that pertains directly to the reason for closure, visible to the poster only." - how would this be different from what the system already provides?

"Actually though, is this site im on right now, not the correct site for 'meta' topics not specific to a single community site? If its specifically a meta for just stackexchange.com then im in the wrong place." - well, that's the thing: there isn't a "just stackexchange.com" - questions only get posted on subdomains or legacy domains like stackoverflow.com. So "meta.stackexchange.com" is overarching for the entire network, yes.

@James that is definitely too much to ask for, because the system already provides you with enough details and in case of an error, there is always meta (not here, but each site's). You don't seem to have read the "tour" on SO after ~16 years; start by reading the provided help, and if you were still not sure ask a specific question about the particular post. Reading the help page will help you to improve your existing and future posts as well.

@Catija Yes, that. I never have had the ability to vote to close issues, or if i do i never used it. So by 'moderators' more accurately what i mean is: Anyone who can for whatever reason do that, should have to Verbalize what about the question would need to change, to not be closed. And ideally that would be its own conversational thread, where others voting to close for other reasons, or for that one, would by the end leave the author with actionable information, also being some minimal amount of proof the voter gave it actual thought.

@M--SavetheDataDump Alternately maybe you are making an ad hominin attack and providing unrequested personal advice instead of actually considering if the idea would improve the sites.

@KarlKnechtel Dude when i said repost, i exactly meant that exact process of editing it to be reopened. You have missed the entire topic of conversation by becoming offended about the idea of me duplicate posting, which is not what i am describing.

@James I did consider it, and it doesn't. By posting to meta, you open the door for some advice regarding your understanding of the network. But maybe you are right. But also consider that maybe it's not the advices if you are offended by almost every comment and answer and vote here. I will not follow this post no more. Cheers.
